# Preventing "Notation Palette" from popping up

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have some session initialization code that loads "Notation" package for each session. This brings up Notation Palette. Any idea how to prevent it, or add code to get rid of it automatically?

OK, belisarius tip solves it, I need to import Notation package as follows

```
Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False;
Needs["Notation`"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Notation.m

> If[ !ValueQ[AutoLoadNotationPalette::usage],
>      AutoLoadNotationPalette::usage =
>         "AutoLoadNotationPalette is a boolean variable. If False then the Notation palette   will not be loaded when the Notation package is loaded. If the value is undefined or True the   Notation palette will be loaded when the Notation package loads. Other package designers can   set this variable outside of the Notation package through a statement similar  to   Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False."
>   ];

HTH!

Comment: Great answer (+1) to a good question (+1). On a related note, I had read through the notations and other add-on code some time ago and was puzzled by this type of construct (i.e., the If[]) being used to define usage messages. This Q/A is a great example of when the approach could be useful---as a way to override behavior of a package that gets loaded at a later time. Me likey learny!